# Dealing with .CSV files and sorting a listarrays into multiple listarrays? - JAVA

Tags: java

So i am trying to sort through a large amount of data in an CSV. file. The file includes a set amount of information for companies, but there are 1000s of companies. For example, I might need to go through 1000 companies, be able to acquire their annual earnings, current stock value, CEO, ect.. each company will have the same information provided (same number of commas but different char lengths), but as the file is a CSV. the company name and information is all separated by commas.

currently i am splitting the csv file into an array via the commas between information. But i want to be able to keep the information together with companies and be able to specify, call and, sort by the given information and company names. But because i have already separated the information via the commas its all listed out already in a listarray.

So is it possible to specify, on a mass scale, that every 15 commas (or splits in the listarray) should be joined back together?? This way each part of the listarray is a separate company. Or is there another way to separate the data so that the information doesnt get split up?

note: there is no similarities in the csv file that would allow me to split information so that it splits after each companies information.

here is a sample of what one of the csv files may look like.

```
"Tiffany & Co. Com",964270,"+0.81","1/14/2014",88.97,93.64,"87.795 - 88.97""Asia Pacific Fund",20700,"+0.04","1/14/2014",10.23,11.37,"10.19 - 10.23""Anadarko Petroleu",4236380,"+2.47","1/14/2014",80.99,98.47,"78.40 - 80.99""Proto Labs, Inc. ",451984,"-0.18","1/14/2014",73.83,89.97,"71.00 - 73.83""Zuoan Fashion Lim",201560,"-0.02","1/14/2014",1.79,3.62,"1.71 - 1.79"
```

Comment: post sample data. It sounds like you need two loops populating a 2-dimensional array. An outer loop to go through all the data (all the companies), and an inner loop that fills in the array with 15 pieces of data.

Comment: You could use the first index of the split line as the key in a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and then keep a list of information objects for the remaining data (assuming that the company name is the first index on each line).

Comment: If this is not a school exercise where you need to write it yourself, consider using a library such as opencsv. Not only will it make your task easier, but it will handle things you may not have thought of such as escaped commas (e.g. if the company name is "Foo, Inc.").

Comment: This questions shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the point that Java is an _Object_ orientated language. Use a library to read your data into a collection of `Company` objects and then do with them what you will. You could even store them into a database and query it.

Comment: I am new to object orientated languages boris. And im trying to get the information into company objects, its just separating the data to be able to place it into the objects. and it looks like dana has suggested a potentially good library to use to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with converting each row of CSV into Java object.
But traditional parsing mechanism is too verbose for me and I might need to handle too many conditions like comma in between quotes, new line character in a column with multiline description. So I suggest you use an existing awesome solution like supercsv.

I also have written a wrapper around it to make developer life easy.

[QuickOCM](http://mkhanal.github.io/quickocm/) will let you do this way.

1. Create a Company class

   ```
    public class Company {

        /* this specifies that 
         * it is a mandatory field in the csv, 
         * of header name "Company Name" and 
         * of type string. 
         * Header is the first line of the csv.
         */
        @ImportField(mandatory = true, name = "Company Name", type = "String")
        public String name;

        @ImportField(mandatory = true, name = "Name of the CEO", type = "String")
        public String ceoName;    
    }
   ```

   You need public getter-setter or public fields, anything works
2. Create csv parser, a handler to handle each row, probably add to a list to sort, and then call parse

   ```
   final List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

   csvParser.process(inputStream, Company.class, new RecordHandler<Company>() {
       @Override
       public void execute(Company imported, int rowNumber, Map supplementaryInfo) {
           companies.add(imported);
       }
   });
   ```
3. Now you can sort the list with by using a sorted list implementation or use a comparator for the same.

For detailed info, you can look into [QuickOCM page](http://mkhanal.github.io/quickocm/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Read{

 String original = "";
 String company = "";
 String otherValue = "";

public Read(String read){

  //here Split the original string into the values 

}

//public void getters and setters

}
```

Then make an array of Read Objects and sort them as you want

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to parse the CSV into objects and then sort those objects.  The object would "know" how many fields it was made up of in the CSV and how to parse each field.  Using the StringTokenizer to parse and a TreeMap to sort would look something like:

```
    ...
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somedata.csv"));
    TreeMap<String, MyObject> map = new TreeMap<>();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(tokens);
        //add the objects to the sorted map, where field1 is what we sort on
        map.put(obj.field1, obj);
    }
    ...
}

static class MyObject {
    //would need the same number of fields as you want to group
    String field1;
    String field2;
    //... so with 2 fields, input is field1,field2,field1,field2,...

    MyObject (StringTokenizer input) {
        this.field1 = input.nextToken();
        this.field2 = input.nextToken();
    }
}
```